# Python Change axis on Multi Histogram plot

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe `df` for which I plot a multi-histogram as follow :

```
df.hist(bins=20)
```

This give me a result that look like this (Yes this exemple is ugly since there is only one data per histogram, sorry) : 
[image]

I have a subplot for each numerical column of my dataframe.

Now I want all my histograms to have an X-axis between 0 and 1. I saw that the hist() function take a `ax` parameter, but I cannot manage to make it work.
How is it possible to do that ?

EDIT :

Here is a minmal example :

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

myArray = [(0,0,0,0,0.5,0,0,0,1),(0,0,0,0,0.5,0,0,0,1)]

myColumns = ['col1','col2','col3','co4','col5','col6','col7','col8','col9']

df = pd.DataFrame(myArray,columns=myColumns)

print(df)
df.hist(bins=20)

plt.show()
```

Comment: So you just want to change the labels of your x-axis?

Comment: In the above example, I want all X-axis to be between 0 and 1. So in the cases the 'blue bar' is at 0, it sould be displayed on the left of the histogram, for a bar at 1 it sould be displayed on the left and for 0.5 it should be on the middle of the histogram.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution that works, but for sure is not ideal:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

myArray = [(0,0,0,0,0.5,0,0,0,1),(0,0,0,0,0.5,0,0,0,1)]

myColumns = ['col1','col2','col3','co4','col5','col6','col7','col8','col9']

df = pd.DataFrame(myArray,columns=myColumns)

print(df)
ax = df.hist(bins=20)
for x in ax:
    for y in x:
        y.set_xlim(0,1)

plt.show()
```

Comment: I arrived at the same solution as you. It does the work but I noticed a weird behavior. Histograms can have different width for the bars. 
For example using `myArray = [(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0), (0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9)]`

Comment: weird, I'm not sure whats causing that behavior. If this solution solved your problem could you mark it as answered? :)